# How do I expand/fill in ID of my products in my excel Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

So my problem is that for previous users who are keeping track of inventory they have labeled items with a ID of example: ABC1234 - ABC1244 but the problem is that when we keep track of our items we need each and ever individual item to be properly accounted for as each item has a unique ID that we track.

So for the past half a year we have been slowly filling in everything and since there are tons of other information in the row that is repeated I was wondering if there was a way to write a VBA macro to expand and insert these rows of data.

So from this

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1234 - ABC1237 | Screw type A |

to this

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1234 | Screw type A |
| ABC1235 | Screw type A |
| ABC1236 | Screw type A |
| ABC1237 | Screw type A |

I have tried using the record macro functions but its not dynamic which is not what I want as the Database can change over time with the influx of new items so I hope there is a way to dynamically complete this process. If anyone knows a solution please help have been banging my head against a wall for awhile now :'D

Comment: You should read [ask] as I don't feel you've described in enough detail for me to even know what you're manually doing. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is what you are looking for.

I am assuming your ABC is always the same, the only thing that is changing is the last 4 number.

[image]

```
Sub Formatting()
    
    Dim xlwrks As Object
    Dim xlrng As Object
    Dim xlcell As Object
    
    Dim lowerlimit As Integer, upperlimit As Integer
    
    Set xlwrks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set xlrng = xlwrks.Range("A2", xlwrks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address) 'from A2 to last cell in column A

    For Each xlcell In xlrng 'iterate ech cell from xlrng
        'e.g splitting this into array of string with the delimiter " - " by using split
        'which will look something like "ABC1234", "ABC1237" for A2 and "ABC1238", "ABC1242" for A3
        'next we only the last 4 number, by using right
        lowerlimit = Right(Split(xlcell.Value2, " - ")(0), 4)
        upperlimit = Right(Split(xlcell.Value2, " - ")(1), 4)
        
        Do Until lowerlimit = upperlimit + 1
            xlwrks.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = "ABC" & lowerlimit
            xlwrks.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = xlcell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            lowerlimit = lowerlimit + 1
        Loop
    Next xlcell

End Sub
```

adding on to the requirement, as mentioned, need to monitor the trend. wrote something to check for the trend instead of manually eyeball the trend. Do note with this, the run time will be longer, because it will loop through each cell to look at the array, it will also loop through each array to look at each character. hope this help happy coding!~~

```
    Dim xlwrks As Object
    Dim xlrng As Object
    Dim xlcell As Object
    
    Dim lowerlimit As Long, upperlimit As Long
    Dim charpos As Integer, characters As String, ID As String
    
    Set xlwrks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set xlrng = xlwrks.Range("A2", xlwrks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address) 'from A2 to last cell in column A

    For Each xlcell In xlrng 'iterate ech cell from xlrng
        'e.g splitting this into array of string with the delimiter " - " by using split
        'which will look something like "ABC1234", "ABC1237" for A2 and "ABC1238", "ABC1242" for A3
        'next we only the last 4 number, by using right
        characters = Split(xlcell.Value2, " - ")(0)
        
        For charpos = 1 To Len(characters)
            If Not IsNumeric(Mid(characters, charpos, 1)) Then
                    ID = ID & Mid(characters, charpos, 1)
                Else
                    Exit For
            End If
        Next charpos
        
        For charpos = 1 To Len(characters)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(characters, charpos, 1)) Then
                lowerlimit = CStr(lowerlimit) & CStr(Mid(characters, charpos, 1))
            End If
        Next charpos
        
        characters = Split(xlcell.Value2, " - ")(1)
        
        For charpos = 1 To Len(characters)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(characters, charpos, 1)) Then
                upperlimit = CStr(upperlimit) & CStr(Mid(characters, charpos, 1))
            End If
        Next charpos
        
        Do Until lowerlimit = upperlimit + 1
            xlwrks.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = ID & lowerlimit
            xlwrks.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = xlcell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            lowerlimit = lowerlimit + 1
        Loop
        
        lowerlimit = 0
        upperlimit = 0
        ID = ""
    Next xlcell
```

Comment: Deleted the previous comment because I realised I just Dim the values as Long for it to work thanks again! It really Helped David! Code works Beautifully, and just to check with you if there is a way to make the lookup Range for the lower and upper limits Dynamic because I have a few more Ids with different letters and length but its not an issue even if you cant. Thanks so much

Comment: no worries, hahah glad you found the solution. the answer is can, but you need to analyse the trend then create a variable to house the strings. I will amend my answer later to include the method. but first do you know it is always 3 letter or it is a mixture of 3 sometimes it is 5 or 4?

Comment: just use the updated code below the original. It should resolve your issue without going to check how many letters and numeric combinations.

Comment: You are a lifesaver David it works perfectly once I append a few information, really helped me with my predicament. Appreciate and thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would not do this with VBA inside the spreadsheet. I would write a separate piece of VB or VBScript that *reads* the existing spreadsheet and produces a new *altered copy* of it.

When it reads a line in the original spreadsheet with just "ABC1234", it just copies that line to the new spreadsheet. When it reads a line that contains "ABC1234 - ABC1237", it recognizes the pattern and figures out how many lines it needs to generate in the new spreadsheet. In this case, it will generate four lines: one line for ABC1234, one line for ABC1235, one line for ABC1236, and one line for ABC1237.

I think this approach will be easier to deal with than a VBA script inside the spreadsheet. You will run it once, check the new spreadsheet, then rename the old one for safe-keeping, and rename the new one to give it the original sheet's name.

Comment: How would you make it recognise the pattern because as I was tinkering I did manage to write something that populates a new sheet with all relevant data to be reorganise but the gruelling part has always been to expand the IDs. I cant figure out a way to actually expand it other than taking the first and last values of the Ids then filling the missing data with the fill function but it requires me to manually place the last code in which is very cumbersome as some may just have 2 ids that need expanding and some that require up to 43!

Comment: I would detect the hyphen, use split() similarly the code in the other answer - but I would also trim to remove extra spaces since users might do that. Assuming that your part numbers are always three letters followed by four digits, I would make sure that the left three chars match in both parts, then I would grab the right 4 chars from each part , convert them both to integers, subtract to find the number of lines that add (it will be one more than the difference), and then loop that many times, incrementing the number by one each time and putting it back together with the three char prefix.